# .htaccess redirect every request to index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server

I am trying to redirect every request to my directory, its sub directory or its file to index.php but I 'm unable to do so.

here is my url
http://www.hypovps.in/images/internal-notes-files/26422supportsmallbiz.jpg

I have placed .htaccess in images.

I want to redirect every request from

```
http://www.hypovps.in/images
http://www.hypovps.in/images/internal-notes-files
http://www.hypovps.in/images/internal-notes-files/26422supportsmallbiz.jpg
```

or any other sub directory/file within /images/ to index.php

Any help will be much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RedirectMatch to redirect /images* to /index.php

```
RedirectMatch ^/images/.+$ /index.php
```